# Show route on error anyway

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have route with next model:

```
model: function model(params) {
  this.store.unloadAll('comment');
  this.get('adapterContext').setRecipeId(params.recipe_id);
  return new _ember['default'].RSVP.hash({
    recipe: this.store.findRecord('recipe', params.recipe_id),
    comments: this.store.findAll('comment')
  });
}
```

In some cases request to `/comments` is failing. But I still want to show current route (just with some visual changes). Now I just get errors in console and transition to route failed. How can I change it?

UPD:

`/comments` returns 500 error from server. And in console I have got `ember.debug.js:30877 Error: Adapter operation failed`.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it seems kind of odd that a promise (asynchronous operation) would block the transition to another route, since the promise itself is being resolved most probably after the transition has already 
happened.
What errors do you get?

Comment: I thought that is default behavior for ember.

Comment: I thought it fails to resolve the promise, not to make the request, sorry. So why wouldn't you fix the error on the server? Alternatively, you might use try catch block on the client to recover from the error, I don't think ember provides something out-of-the-box.

Comment: I want to be sure that app will work even if 'comments' part not. So I want just handle server error in this case and hide comments section in hbs.

Comment: I would go with that https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch in this case. Haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

When a promise returned by model hook fails, the `error` event is triggered. So you can handle it in your actions' error hook such that:

```
actions: {
    error(error, transition) {
       if (error) {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

[Here it is](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-error-code-event) in the Ember Guide. It describes clearly.

If failure your `comments` promise is ignorable, but failure of `recipe` is not, I can suggest you to put `recipe` and `comments` promises in to different routes. For example, `recipe` in the parent route and `comments` in the child route. So when an error occured in `comments` promises; you can display your recipe releated templates but not comments releated templates.